# Postgres auto_explain works with SELECT but not with COPY table_name FROM STDIN (FORMAT binary)

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I'm trying to debug some performance issues due to some random queries that are suffering from too long duration, so I've updated my `postgresql.conf` with:

```
session_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'
auto_explain.log_analyze = 'on'
auto_explain.log_min_duration = 1
```

When the connection from my python script executes `SELECT pg_sleep(1)`,
I can see in the log file the following:

```
2022-02-08 20:22:17.737 UTC [163] LOG:  duration: 1000.841 ms  plan:
#011Query Text: SELECT pg_sleep(1)
#011Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1000.829..1000.830 rows=1 loops=1)
2022-02-08 20:22:17.737 UTC [163] LOG:  duration: 1001.394 ms  statement: SELECT pg_sleep(1)
```

However, when the connection from my python script executes `COPY {table_name} FROM STDIN {opts}`,
I only get this in the log file:

```
2022-02-08 17:36:45.958 UTC [3079] LOG:  duration: 1618.155 ms  statement: COPY "my_table" FROM STDIN (FORMAT binary)
```

**Question:**
Any ideas why the plan is missing on the last query ?

Comment: What's your postgresql version?

Comment: COPY is not something eligible for explain.  Just like it doesn't work if you manually put `EXPLAIN` in front of it.

Comment: But as a special case it does work if you copy a query *out*, `copy (select * from pgbench_accounts) to...`. It doesn't even need auto_explain.log_nested_statements=on.

Comment: @MAM, I'm running on Postgresql 14

Comment: @jjanes, well that's make sense. Are you familiar with more commands that are not eligible to explain ?

Comment: I found this if it helps 

>You cannot use EXPLAIN for all kinds of statements: it only supports SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE (of a prepared statement), CREATE TABLE ... AS and DECLARE (of a cursor).

reference: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/how-to-interpret-postgresql-explain-analyze-output/